# Twitter Bootstrap logo next to nav bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I searched around SO and I haven't found a similar question / solution.

I'd like to align the logo to the left of the innner-navbar.

My current HTML is-

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav"> .........
```

Which which would look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUbYI.jpg

Comment: have you tried to add .pull-left class to the logo?

Comment: @JoãoRafaelMartins I did to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add spanX to them ex:
[**DEMO**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yhcfnppe)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo span2"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
  <div class="navbar span9">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav"> .........
```

is that what you want?